ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME error when importing from "astro:" in a custom script with tsx. How to use 'astro:content' in a standalone script?
I have an astro project in which I'm building a custom typescript script for creating draft blog posts. I am running the script directly using tsx.
When I run the script, I always get an error when I try to import from "astro:content".
utils.ts script file to be run with tsx. It worked until I added an import from "astro:content":
import { getEntry, type CollectionEntry } from "astro:content";
...

tsx v4.11.0 is installed globally
node v21.6.0 is used
command run, using the default astro tsconfig:
tsx --tsconfig ./tsconfig.json ./src/utils/utils.ts create-post

tsconfig.json:
{
  "extends": "astro/tsconfigs/base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "jsxImportSource": "preact"
  }
}

output:
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ESM_URL_SCHEME]: Only URLs with a scheme in: file, data, and node are supported by the default ESM loader. Received protocol 'astro:'

I want to reference a content collection (of photos) with this script for generating a draft blog post in another content collection. I want to do this programatically, outside of the astro runtime/build.
The script worked, but once I added the import for getEntry from astro:content I started getting the above error. The same import works inside .astro components and layouts, but not as mentioned above in a standalone script. I am not sure if the issue is with tsx, tsconfig.json, or something astro specific.

Astro is running vite over things, probably with a custom plugin. You might be able to import the file directly from node_modules/ though...
